# How can I use generic formatter on multiple SlickGrid s?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, grid, slickgrid

I am developing a web app using SlickGrid.

Our application has many grids in different tabs/pages and for that reason I am wondering if I  can refactor some code so that I am not writing the same functions over and over for seperate grids.

An example:
I need a custom Formatter since we have multiple tree grids (the formatter to implement the tree structure is identical for each grid.):
    function PercentCompleteFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext)

Given that I cannot pass the grid or a dataview as an arguement (assuming the signature above must be used for all custom formatter.), I basically have to have the same formatter code inside each code block where I am creating the grid.

Is there a way I can create one "generic" formatter and apply it to ALL grids?

The same question applies to things like sorting, filtering, etc... but I hope the above explaination covers what I'm trying to ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jQuery's .proxy() helper (or similar) to bind a function to a particular context.

For example:

```
function MyFormatter(row, cell, value) { 
  var grid = this;  // the grid will be the executing scope
  // ...
}

var myFormatterForGridA = $.proxy(MyFormatter, gridA);
var myFormatterForGridB = $.proxy(MyFormatter, gridB);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works perfectly for me! (Apologies for not voting this up, new to site so my rep is not high enough to allow it yet.)